# Automatically adjust the width of a table column to the cell content

Tags: tables, tabularx, tabulary

I would like to create a table and automatically adjust the width of the different columns to fit their content. With the traditional `tabular` environment, the table exceeds the page borders. `tabulary` generates too narrow columns and overlapped texts. I was not successful in implementing `tabularx`. Note that I need a multirow cell for the first and last columns, and a continuous horizontal line for the other columns.

Any solution would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
        \caption{TABLE TITLE}
        %\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{|C|C|C|C|C|C|}         
            \hline
            \textbf{Col. 1} & \textbf{Col. 2: Very very very long title} & \textbf{Col. 3: Very very long title} & \textbf{Col. 4: Very long title} & \textbf{Col. 5: Very very long title} & \textbf{Col. 6: Very very very long title} \\   \hline  \hline
            
            \textbf{Line 1} &
            \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} Sensor1 \\ \hline Sensor2 \end{tabular} &
            \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} $(10.0, 12.3)$ \\ \hline $(4.2, 9.3)$ \end{tabular} &
            \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} 12.4 \\ \hline 9.9 \end{tabular} &
            \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} 2.0 \\ \hline 3.3 \end{tabular}  &
            0.4 \\   \hline
        \end{tabulary}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why the nested `tabular` ??? they prevent all linebreaking so stop tabularx or tabulary doing anything useful

Comment: I was trying to create multirow cells.

Comment: but tabularx and tabulary cells are multiple line parboxes, that is the whole point of the packages: to choose suitable widths for linebreaking within the columns.,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I'm not good with tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I updated my answer after the OP stated that they need a continuous line to span columns 2 thru 5 in the first data row. Further update after learning the OP wants vertical rules as well.)

No problems when using a `tabularx` setup. Note that columns 2 thru 6 all have the same width.

I'd also recommend doing away with the borderline vulgar-looking **bold-facing** in the header row and the left-hand column.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\Centering' macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules

\begin{document}

% First table: no vertical rules, well-spaced horizontal rules
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Table Title \strut}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l CCCCC @{}}         
\toprule
Col.\ 1 & 
Col.\ 2\newline Very very very long title & 
Col.\ 3\newline Very very long title & 
Col.\ 4\newline Very long title & 
Col.\ 5\newline Very very long title & 
Col.\ 6\newline Very very very long title \\  
\midrule
   \multirow{2.3}{*}{Line 1} 
   & Sensor 1 & (10.0, 12.3) & 12.4 & 2.0 & 
   \multirow{2.3}{*}{0.4} \\
   \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
   & Sensor 2 & (4.2, 9.3) & 9.9 & 3.3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

%% Second table: vertical rules
\begin{table}[h]
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}      % default: 6pt
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less-cramped "look"
\caption{Same table as before, but now with vertical rules \strut}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|C|C|C|C|C|}         
\hline
Col.\ 1 & 
Col.\ 2\newline Very very very long title & 
Col.\ 3\newline Very very long title & 
Col.\ 4\newline Very long title & 
Col.\ 5\newline Very very long title & 
Col.\ 6\newline Very very very long title \\  
\hline
   \multirow{2.1}{*}{Line 1} 
   & Sensor 1 & (10.0, 12.3) & 12.4 & 2.0 & 
   \multirow{2.1}{*}{0.4} \\
   \cline{2-5}
   & Sensor 2 & (4.2, 9.3) & 9.9 & 3.3 & \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Mico, but I need a continuous horizontal line break for the 4 middle columns, in addition to vertical line separation for the columns.

Comment: @AEW - Then why did you use `tabular` environments in your sample code?

Comment: I was trying to create multirow cells, following an example. I'm not good with tables.

Comment: @AEW - Please see my updated answer. I think I know what a "continuous horizontal line" (across columns 2 thru 5) means. I'm afraid I don't know what a "continuous horizontal line break" might mean.

Comment: That's good, thank you. Can you also add continuous vertical line separation between the columns? This `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|@{} l |C|C|C|C|C| @{}|}` does not do it.

Comment: @AEW - I've updated my answer some more. Speaking for myself, I can see no good reason for using vertical rules in a table.

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understood your question, than you after something like this:

[image]

For this table I use `\f0otnotesize` font size, `tblr` of `tabularray` package and for first and last cell at bottom use multirow cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
%   \usepackage{geometry}   % for setting page layout
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}  % added
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{TABLE TITLE}
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 colsep ={3pt},
                 colspec={Q[l, font=\bfseries] *{5}{X[c]}},
                 cell{Y}{1,Z} = {r=2}{},    % defined multi row cells
                 row{1} ={font=\bfseries}
                 }
Col. 1 
    & Col. 2: Very very very long title 
        & Col. 3: Very very long title
            & Col. 4: Very long title
                & Col. 5: Very very long title 
                    & Col. 6: Very very very long title \\
Line 1 
    &   Sensor1
        & (10.0, 12.3)
            &   12.4 
                &   2.0 
                    &   0.4 \\   
    &   Sensor2
        &   (4.2, 9.3)
            &   9.9
                &   3.3
                    &   0.4 \\
        \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
You may consider to use abbreviation for long column titles and explain their meaning in table notes, something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%   \usepackage{geometry}   % for setting page layout
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{talltblr}[
caption={TABLE TITLE},
 note{} = {\footnotesize
            \begin{enumerate*}[label=\textsuperscript{\alph*}, itemjoin={{; }}]
           \item    Very very very long title
           \item    Very very long title
           \item    Very long title
           \item    Very very long title
           \item    Very very very long title
           \end{enumerate*}}
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                 colsep=3pt,
                 colspec={Q[l, font=\bfseries] *{5}{X[c]}},
                 cell{Y}{1,Z} = {r=2}{},    % defined multi row cells
                 row{1} ={font=\bfseries}
                 }
Col. 1 
    & Col. 2\TblrNote{a} 
        & Col. 3\TblrNote{b}
            & Col. 4\TblrNote{c}
                & Col. 5\TblrNote{d}
                    & Col. 6\TblrNote{e} \\
Line 1 
    &   Sensor1
        & (10.0, 12.3)
            &   12.4 
                &   2.0 
                    &   0.4 \\   
    &   Sensor2
        &   (4.2, 9.3)
            &   9.9
                &   3.3
                    &   0.4 \\
        \end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```